# Cassandra 3.10 - LEAK DETECTED & Stream failed

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I want to add or remove nodes to the cluster.
When I tring to add/remove node, I get a LEAK DETECTED and a STREAM FAILED ERROR messange.

If I drop the index - pushcapabilityindx,presetsearchval - before adding / removing nodes, the node add / remove succeeds.
If there is no data update, the data of abc_db.sub is automatically deleted after 24 hours. (TTL 86400 sec)
Also, if I do not have any work including index deletion, add / remove nodes  succeeds normally after 14 days.

Where should I start troubleshooting this error?

```
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.10 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
```

```
CREATE TABLE abc_db.sub (
    phoneno text,
    deviceid text,
    subid text,
    callbackdata text,
    corelator text,
    duration int,
    local_index bigint,
    phase int,
    presetsearchvalue text,
    pushcapability list<text>,
    pushtoken text,
    pushtype text,
    searchcriteria frozen<typesearchcriteria>,
    PRIMARY KEY (phoneno, deviceid, subid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (deviceid ASC, subid ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
CREATE INDEX pushcapabilityindx ON abc_db.sub (values(pushcapability));
CREATE INDEX presetsearchval ON abc_db.sub (presetsearchvalue);
```

```
INFO  [main] 2019-05-09 07:57:15,741 StorageService.java:1435 - JOINING: waiting for schema information to complete
INFO  [main] 2019-05-09 07:57:16,497 StorageService.java:1435 - JOINING: schema complete, ready to bootstrap
INFO  [main] 2019-05-09 07:57:16,497 StorageService.java:1435 - JOINING: waiting for pending range calculation
INFO  [main] 2019-05-09 07:57:16,497 StorageService.java:1435 - JOINING: calculation complete, ready to bootstrap
INFO  [main] 2019-05-09 07:57:16,498 StorageService.java:1435 - JOINING: getting bootstrap token
INFO  [main] 2019-05-09 07:57:16,531 StorageService.java:1435 - JOINING: sleeping 30000 ms for pending range setup
INFO  [main] 2019-05-09 07:57:46,532 StorageService.java:1435 - JOINING: Starting to bootstrap...
INFO  [main] 2019-05-09 07:57:47,775 StreamResultFuture.java:90 - [Stream #21f71b70-7230-11e9-9495-ab5d6d9b9488] Executing streaming plan for Bootstrap
INFO  [StreamConnectionEstablisher:1] 2019-05-09 07:57:47,783 StreamSession.java:266 - [Stream #21f71b70-7230-11e9-9495-ab5d6d9b9488] Starting streaming to /172.50.20.10
INFO  [StreamConnectionEstablisher:1] 2019-05-09 07:57:47,786 StreamCoordinator.java:264 - [Stream #21f71b70-7230-11e9-9495-ab5d6d9b9488, ID#0] Beginning stream session with /172.50.20.10
INFO  [STREAM-IN-/172.50.20.10:5000] 2019-05-09 07:57:48,887 StreamResultFuture.java:173 - [Stream #21f71b70-7230-11e9-9495-ab5d6d9b9488 ID#0] Prepare completed. Receiving 261 files(1012.328MiB), sending 0 files(0.000KiB)
INFO  [StreamConnectionEstablisher:2] 2019-05-09 07:57:48,891 StreamSession.java:266 - [Stream #21f71b70-7230-11e9-9495-ab5d6d9b9488] Starting streaming to /172.50.22.10
INFO  [StreamConnectionEstablisher:2] 2019-05-09 07:57:48,893 StreamCoordinator.java:264 - [Stream #21f71b70-7230-11e9-9495-ab5d6d9b9488, ID#0] Beginning stream session with /172.50.22.10
INFO  [STREAM-IN-/172.50.22.10:5000] 2019-05-09 07:57:50,020 StreamResultFuture.java:173 - [Stream #21f71b70-7230-11e9-9495-ab5d6d9b9488 ID#0] Prepare completed. Receiving 254 files(1.286GiB), sending 0 files(0.000KiB)
INFO  [StreamConnectionEstablisher:3] 2019-05-09 07:57:50,022 StreamSession.java:266 - [Stream #21f71b70-7230-11e9-9495-ab5d6d9b9488] Starting streaming to /172.50.21.10
INFO  [StreamConnectionEstablisher:3] 2019-05-09 07:57:50,025 StreamCoordinator.java:264 - [Stream #21f71b70-7230-11e9-9495-ab5d6d9b9488, ID#0] Beginning stream session with /172.50.21.10
INFO  [STREAM-IN-/172.50.21.10:5000] 2019-05-09 07:57:50,998 StreamResultFuture.java:173 - [Stream #21f71b70-7230-11e9-9495-ab5d6d9b9488 ID#0] Prepare completed. Receiving 114 files(1.085GiB), sending 0 files(0.000KiB)
INFO  [StreamReceiveTask:1] 2019-05-09 07:58:02,509 SecondaryIndexManager.java:365 - Submitting index build of pushcapabilityindx,presetsearchval for data in BigTableReader(path='/cassandra/data/abc_db/sub-28f738d0627f11e9b62cc50700a5eaee/mc-1-big-Data.db'),BigTableReader(path='/cassandra/data/abc_db/sub-28f738d0627f11e9b62cc50700a5eaee/mc-2-big-Data.db'),BigTableReader(path='/cassandra/data/abc_db/sub-28f738d0627f11e9b62cc50700a5eaee/mc-3-big-Data.db')
INFO  [StreamReceiveTask:1] 2019-05-09 07:58:02,519 SecondaryIndexManager.java:385 - Index build of pushcapabilityindx,presetsearchval complete
INFO  [StreamReceiveTask:1] 2019-05-09 07:58:11,213 SecondaryIndexManager.java:365 - Submitting index build of pushcapabilityindx,presetsearchval for data in BigTableReader(path='/cassandra/data/abc_db/sub-28f738d0627f11e9b62cc50700a5eaee/mc-4-big-Data.db'),BigTableReader(path='/cassandra/data/abc_db/sub-28f738d0627f11e9b62cc50700a5eaee/mc-5-big-Data.db'),BigTableReader(path='/cassandra/data/abc_db/sub-28f738d0627f11e9b62cc50700a5eaee/mc-6-big-Data.db'),BigTableReader(path='/cassandra/data/abc_db/sub-28f738d0627f11e9b62cc50700a5eaee/mc-7-big-Data.db'),BigTableReader(path='/cassandra/data/abc_db/sub-28f738d0627f11e9b62cc50700a5eaee/mc-8-big-Data.db'),BigTableReader(path='/cassandra/data/abc_db/sub-28f738d0627f11e9b62cc50700a5eaee/mc-9-big-Data.db')
ERROR [StreamReceiveTask:1] 2019-05-09 07:58:11,295 StreamSession.java:593 - [Stream #21f71b70-7230-11e9-9495-ab5d6d9b9488] Streaming error occurred on session with peer 172.50.22.10
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.Throwables.maybeFail(Throwables.java:51) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFutures(FBUtilities.java:393) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.SecondaryIndexManager.buildIndexesBlocking(SecondaryIndexManager.java:382) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.SecondaryIndexManager.buildAllIndexesBlocking(SecondaryIndexManager.java:269) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamReceiveTask$OnCompletionRunnable.run(StreamReceiveTask.java:215) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:79) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFutures(FBUtilities.java:386) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.AbstractIterator.next(AbstractIterator.java:64) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.SecondaryIndexManager.lambda$indexPartition$20(SecondaryIndexManager.java:618) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.SecondaryIndexManager.indexPartition(SecondaryIndexManager.java:618) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.internal.CollatedViewIndexBuilder.build(CollatedViewIndexBuilder.java:71) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$14.run(CompactionManager.java:1587) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_191]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
ERROR [STREAM-IN-/172.50.22.10:5000] 2019-05-09 07:58:11,305 StreamSession.java:593 - [Stream #21f71b70-7230-11e9-9495-ab5d6d9b9488] Streaming error occurred on session with peer 172.50.22.10
java.lang.RuntimeException: Outgoing stream handler has been closed
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler.sendMessage(ConnectionHandler.java:143) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.receive(StreamSession.java:655) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.messageReceived(StreamSession.java:523) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$IncomingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:317) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
INFO  [StreamReceiveTask:1] 2019-05-09 07:58:11,310 StreamResultFuture.java:187 - [Stream #21f71b70-7230-11e9-9495-ab5d6d9b9488] Session with /172.50.22.10 is complete
ERROR [Reference-Reaper:1] 2019-05-09 07:58:19,115 Ref.java:224 - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref$State@441b19c1) to class org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.WrappedSharedCloseable$Tidy@1255997234:[[OffHeapBitSet]] was not released before the reference was garbage collected
ERROR [Reference-Reaper:1] 2019-05-09 07:58:19,115 Ref.java:224 - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref$State@4ee372b1) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SafeMemory$MemoryTidy@199357705:Memory@[7f12a4ad4970..7f12a4ad4a10) was not released before the reference was garbage collected
ERROR [Reference-Reaper:1] 2019-05-09 07:58:19,115 Ref.java:224 - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref$State@172830a5) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SafeMemory$MemoryTidy@983595037:Memory@[7f12a4b3f670..7f12a4b3f990) was not released before the reference was garbage collected
ERROR [Reference-Reaper:1] 2019-05-09 07:58:19,116 Ref.java:224 - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref$State@6f83e302) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SafeMemory$MemoryTidy@1808665158:Memory@[7f12a41a56d0..7f12a41a56d4) was not released before the reference was garbage collected
INFO  [StreamReceiveTask:1] 2019-05-09 07:58:40,657 SecondaryIndexManager.java:365 - Submitting index build of groupchatid_idx_giinfo for data in BigTableReader(path='/cassandra/data/srib_storeserver_objectstore_db/groupinfoobjects-28134170627f11e9b62cc50700a5eaee/mc-1-big-Data.db'),BigTableReader(path='/cassandra/data/srib_storeserver_objectstore_db/groupinfoobjects-28134170627f11e9b62cc50700a5eaee/mc-2-big-Data.db')
INFO  [StreamReceiveTask:1] 2019-05-09 07:58:40,714 SecondaryIndexManager.java:385 - Index build of groupchatid_idx_giinfo complete
INFO  [StreamReceiveTask:1] 2019-05-09 07:58:41,494 SecondaryIndexManager.java:365 - Submitting index build of groupchatid_idx_giinfo for data in BigTableReader(path='/cassandra/data/srib_storeserver_objectstore_db/groupinfoobjects-28134170627f11e9b62cc50700a5eaee/mc-3-big-Data.db'),BigTableReader(path='/cassandra/data/srib_storeserver_objectstore_db/groupinfoobjects-28134170627f11e9b62cc50700a5eaee/mc-4-big-Data.db'),BigTableReader(path='/cassandra/data/srib_storeserver_objectstore_db/groupinfoobjects-28134170627f11e9b62cc50700a5eaee/mc-5-big-Data.db'),BigTableReader(path='/cassandra/data/srib_storeserver_objectstore_db/groupinfoobjects-28134170627f11e9b62cc50700a5eaee/mc-6-big-Data.db'),BigTableReader(path='/cassandra/data/srib_storeserver_objectstore_db/groupinfoobjects-28134170627f11e9b62cc50700a5eaee/mc-7-big-Data.db')
INFO  [StreamReceiveTask:1] 2019-05-09 07:58:41,537 SecondaryIndexManager.java:385 - Index build of groupchatid_idx_giinfo complete
INFO  [StreamReceiveTask:1] 2019-05-09 07:58:43,175 SecondaryIndexManager.java:365 - Submitting index build of pushcapabilityindx,presetsearchval for data in BigTableReader(path='/cassandra/data/abc_db/sub-28f738d0627f11e9b62cc50700a5eaee/mc-11-big-Data.db')
INFO  [StreamReceiveTask:1] 2019-05-09 07:58:43,209 SecondaryIndexManager.java:385 - Index build of pushcapabilityindx,presetsearchval complete
INFO  [StreamReceiveTask:1] 2019-05-09 07:58:43,972 StreamResultFuture.java:187 - [Stream #21f71b70-7230-11e9-9495-ab5d6d9b9488] Session with /172.50.20.10 is complete
INFO  [StreamReceiveTask:1] 2019-05-09 07:58:45,643 StreamResultFuture.java:187 - [Stream #21f71b70-7230-11e9-9495-ab5d6d9b9488] Session with /172.50.21.10 is complete
WARN  [StreamReceiveTask:1] 2019-05-09 07:58:45,664 StreamResultFuture.java:214 - [Stream #21f71b70-7230-11e9-9495-ab5d6d9b9488] Stream failed
WARN  [StreamReceiveTask:1] 2019-05-09 07:58:45,665 StorageService.java:1497 - Error during bootstrap.
org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.management.StreamEventJMXNotifier.onFailure(StreamEventJMXNotifier.java:88) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1310) [guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457) [guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156) [guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145) [guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:202) [guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.maybeComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:215) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.handleSessionComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:191) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.closeSession(StreamSession.java:481) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.maybeCompleted(StreamSession.java:766) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.taskCompleted(StreamSession.java:727) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamReceiveTask$OnCompletionRunnable.run(StreamReceiveTask.java:244) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:79) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
ERROR [main] 2019-05-09 07:58:45,665 StorageService.java:1507 - Error while waiting on bootstrap to complete. Bootstrap will have to be restarted.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.bootstrap(StorageService.java:1502) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:962) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:681) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:612) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:394) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:601) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:735) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.management.StreamEventJMXNotifier.onFailure(StreamEventJMXNotifier.java:88) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1310) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:202) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.maybeComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:215) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.handleSessionComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:191) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.closeSession(StreamSession.java:481) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.maybeCompleted(StreamSession.java:766) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.taskCompleted(StreamSession.java:727) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamReceiveTask$OnCompletionRunnable.run(StreamReceiveTask.java:244) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:79) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
WARN  [main] 2019-05-09 07:58:45,676 StorageService.java:1013 - Some data streaming failed. Use nodetool to check bootstrap state and resume. For more, see `nodetool help bootstrap`. IN_PROGRESS
INFO  [main] 2019-05-09 07:58:45,677 CassandraDaemon.java:694 - Waiting for gossip to settle before accepting client requests...
INFO  [main] 2019-05-09 07:58:53,678 CassandraDaemon.java:725 - No gossip backlog; proceeding
INFO  [main] 2019-05-09 07:58:53,737 NativeTransportService.java:70 - Netty using native Epoll event loop
INFO  [main] 2019-05-09 07:58:53,781 Server.java:155 - Using Netty Version: [netty-buffer=netty-buffer-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-codec=netty-codec-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-codec-haproxy=netty-codec-haproxy-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-codec-http=netty-codec-http-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-codec-socks=netty-codec-socks-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-common=netty-common-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-handler=netty-handler-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-tcnative=netty-tcnative-1.1.33.Fork19.fe4816e, netty-transport=netty-transport-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-transport-native-epoll=netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-transport-rxtx=netty-transport-rxtx-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-transport-sctp=netty-transport-sctp-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-transport-udt=netty-transport-udt-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86]
INFO  [main] 2019-05-09 07:58:53,781 Server.java:156 - Starting listening for CQL clients on /172.50.20.11:7042 (unencrypted)...
INFO  [main] 2019-05-09 07:58:53,809 CassandraDaemon.java:528 - Not starting RPC server as requested. Use JMX (StorageService->startRPCServer()) or nodetool (enablethrift) to start it
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by myself.

```
No. Linux  OS          Package version  RESULT
1   Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS  deb 3.10    Stream Failed
2   Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS  deb 3.11.4  Stream Failed
3   Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS  tgz 3.11.4  Successful
4   Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS  deb 3.10    Stream Failed
5   Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS  deb 3.11.4  Stream Failed
6   Debian GNU/Linux 9.9 (stretch)  deb 3.10    Stream Failed
7   Debian GNU/Linux 9.9 (stretch)  deb 3.11.4  Stream Failed
8   Amazon Linux 2  rpm 3.11.4  Successful
9   CentOS 7.6  rpm 3.11.4  Successful
```

Finally, I am going to install from binary tarball files.

I am not a developer, so I can not find the cause.
I hope someone finds the cause and fixes it in Ubuntu & Debian.

Regards.

Sungjae Yun.

Comment: I recommend to open JIRA against Cassandra to bring this problem to attention of developers